# reledmac: Customize style of a footnote that spans a page break?

Tags: reledmac

We use reledmac to place exclusively critical footnotes (`\Xfootnote`) that are printed at the bottom of the page.
Often, a note spans several lines, and occasionally it spans a page break too.

Line numbers for such footnotes are printed as follows (say the note goes **from** p. 1, l. 10 **to** p. 2, l. 1).

The standard style is **1.10–2.1**:
[image: the current format]

However, our edition's stylesheet requires the format **10–S.~2.1**:
[image: the desired format]

In other words:

(1) We would like to remove the number of the *starting page*, **if** it is identical with the *current* page number. (For consistency reasons, as the majority of footnotes only get a line number and no page number.)

(2) We would like to insert a prefix to the *end-page* number. In our case, `S\fullstop~` or the like.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec]{reledmac}

\lineation{page}    
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}    

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
%
\pstart
\setline{10}
%
\edtext{Lorem}{%
\Afootnote{A critical note that is confined to one page.}}
%
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
%
\edtext{eiusmod 
\ledpb
tempor incididunt.}{%
\Afootnote{A critical note that spans a page break.}}
%
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

I don't believe that reledmac has a parameter to customize the page/line range in this way.

I did find a workaround to generate the desired output (as seen in the second picture), but it's hacky and ugly and not a good idea in the long run; that was by copying the definition of `\printlines` in our preamble and making suitable changes (to lines 3897-3900 and l. 3940 in reledmac.sty, v 2.37.2).

Is there a better way to do this, other than to patch or hack the definition of `\printlines`?
Or could I request a new feature to customize the page/line range in this regard?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can open a github issue

Comment: Thanks @Maïeul – opened an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reledmac 2.38.0, just send on CTAN, I have added two features :

- `\Xbeforepagenumber{<txt>}` to add a text before the page number
- `\Xnopagenumberifcurrent` to remove page number for the current page. Not that, because of the complexity of getting the current page number, this feature need more runs (for cross-referencing).

So your example becomes :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,nofamiliar,noeledsec]{reledmac}

\lineation{page}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\Xnopagenumberifcurrent
\Xbeforepagenumber{S}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
%
\pstart
\setline{10}
%
\edtext{Lorem}{%
\Afootnote{A critical note that is confined to one page.}}
%
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
%
\edtext{eiusmod
\ledpb
tempor incididunt.}{%
\Afootnote{A critical note that spans a page break.}}
%
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for adding this!